# Why does my consumer-producer setup only output the first item?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm a beginner, trying to work out multithreading and the consumer-producer pattern. As a simple test, I am trying to write something that will output the numbers 1 to 500. Here's what I've written.

```
array = [*1..500]

queue = SizedQueue.new(5)

p1 = Thread.new do
  array.each do |n|
    queue << lambda {
      puts n
    }
  end
  queue << "done"
end

consumer = Thread.new do
  item = queue.pop(true)
  Thread.exit if item == "done"
  item.call
end

consumer.join
```

So I have an array `[1,2,3,4...]`, and a queue that fits 5 item. For each item in the array, I add to the queue a lambda which will output that item, and at the very end, the value "done".

Then I start a consumer. I get an item from the queue. If it's "done" then I end the program. If it's not, then it must be one of my number-output lambdas, so I call it.

But the output is only ever `1`. A single number 1. I can't understand why, the logic all seems sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the consumer thread. Threads do not by default loop through the passed code block.

```
consumer = Thread.new do
    while queue.empty? == false
      item = queue.pop(true)
      Thread.exit if item == "done"
      item.call
    end  
end
```